# Issues related to windows process administrator permissions

Tags: c++, windows

I know very little about windows api, but now I need to implement some functionality using them.

Before deleting a file, I need to check the write permission of the current folder. If administrative permission is required to write, use administrator permission to delete. If administrator permission is not required, use non-administrator permission to delete.

My current process is started with administrator privileges. How should I adjust the permissions of the current process?

I used OpenProcessToken, LookupPrivilegeValue and AdjustTokenPrivilege to turn off the process SE_DEBUG_NAME permissions, and then when I deleted a file that could not be deleted by ordinary users, the file was indeed deleted. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?
[folder Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doYWw.png)
[file Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egCdg.png)

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

bool SetPrivilege(bool bEnablePrivilege)
{
    HANDLE hToken = nullptr;
    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken))
    {
        std::cout << "OpenProcessToken error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "hToken: " << hToken << std::endl;

    LUID luid;
    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid))
    {
        std::cout << "LookupPrivilegeValue error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege)
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    else
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, (PDWORD)NULL))
    {
        std::cout << "AdjustTokenPrivileges error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
    {
        std::cout << "The token does not have the specified privilege." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main() 
{
    if (!SetPrivilege(false))
    {
        std::cout << "SetPrivilege failed!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    LPCWSTR filePath = L"C:\\Users\\SH0249\\Desktop\\floder\\sample.txt";
    DeleteFile(filePath);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, SE_DEBUG_NAME is irrelevant here; you want SE_RESTORE_NAME instead. Second, the permissions aren't enough; you need to explicitly deny write/delete access to your account. Then you'll only be able to delete the file when you enable the privilege (it is disabled by default).